# Using Daily/Alpha/Beta Builds Through Release

Tags: upgrade, daily-build

Heyo! I had a quick question about what happens when you use pre-release builds during and past the release they're intended for. Some clarification;

Hypothetically, I'm running a daily-live build of Ubuntu. Right now, that puts me I'm the release path of 17.10 (Artful Aardvark). If I were to run this, up to date, beyond the release of 17.10, I could use `sudo do-release-upgrade` (IIRC) to update/upgrade my system to that release, changing my update and support cycle to that of 17.10.

What would be the outcome if I just maintained the path I was on? Using just `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` to update my system. Would I hypothetically be able to continue using a daily-live build? Would it eventually put me on track for the next release after, in this case, 18.04? Meaning at that point `sudo do-release-upgrade` will launch me into 18.04? Or will this update and build path be cut off when its intended release candidate 17.10 is pushed?

Comment: As soon as you install the updates available after the official release it should be the same as installing that same release.

Comment: Ah, but would I be on the same update path? Say, would I still keep getting daily-live updates, or would I be thrown into the 17.10 track? As an example, if I updated my 16.04 install, I'd still be using 16.04, unless I did `sudo do-release-upgrade`, which would upgrade my system to the current release. Does daily-live exhibit similar behavior? (Thanks for the comment, by the way.)

Comment: As I said it's the same. A "release" represents a point in time where most of the packages are frozen in a given version (Firefox and Chromium are exceptions), only receiving security updates if needed. A few other distros use a different model, rolling release, which continuously updates (less stable).

Comment: Just looking at your `sources.list` will answer the question...

Comment: You don't seem to be understanding my question. I wouldn't be using 17.10, I'd be using a daily-live build. I won't be upgrading it, I'll be updating it. My question, once again, is if I continue to update this same system, will I be able to maintain this further than just the release it's intended for. In other words, can I use it throughout 17.10, or even 18.04 in the way I am now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike Debian, Ubuntu does not have a rolling, next-release repository. There's nothing comparable to `testing` or `sid`. Until release, the repositories of that release get updated, and the contents of the daily build are updated to reflect that. Post-release, the main repository is frozen (updates for that version go to `<release>-security`, `<release>-updates`, `<release>-proposed`, etc.).

You may *start* from a daily build, but that just means you're using whichever version's repository that daily build used. After the installation, all upgrades are a matter of the repositories used. Post-release, the daily builds are updated to use the *next* release's repositories. And your installed Ubuntu isn't.

So: until release, running `apt update`/`apt upgrade` should mostly keep you in sync with the daily builds, but post-release, that won't be true.